# Simpler formula for $\frac{(pn)!}{(p!)^k(p(n-k))!}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $n,p,k$ be non-negative integers ($p$ prime, but not important here). I wondered if there is a more closed-form (i.e., simpler) formula for

$$A(p,n,k)=\frac{(pn)!}{(p!)^k(p(n-k))!}$$

and more precisely for

$$A(p,n)=\sum_{k=1}^n A(p,n,k).$$

I know that for $k=1$, $A(p,n,k)=\binom{pn}{p}$, but that's about it what I can figure out.

Comment: There is no such thing as "more closed-form". An expression is either a closed-form one or not.

Comment: Now, the linguists are flocking in :) Thanks, but then just read it vaguely as "simpler".

Comment: @vrugtehagel In a sense, your comment is comic though. The term "closed-form" is not a precise mathematical term, but used vaguely among mathematicians (see e.g. Wikipedia or many other sources). But now you say this vagueness is either true or not, which is apparently a contradiction.

Comment: Well, the term "closed-form" has a definition and with that, one can determine any expression to be closed-form or not. It's a mathematical term and not at all vague.

Comment: Does it? Wikipedia doesn't agree with you:  "The set of operations and functions admitted in a closed-form expression may vary with author and context."

Comment: Stop this discussion. Perhaps I suppose another simple form.

Comment: The set of natural numbers also may vary with author and context. That doesn't make it vague or non-mathematical. Takahiro is right though, we shouldn't argue over this. It's not relevant to the question, since you already cleared up what you meant.

Comment: It either includes 0 or not. It doesn't vary in unpredictable ways as "closed-form" does: "It may contain constants, variables, certain "well-known" operations (e.g., + − × ÷), and functions (e.g., nth root, exponent, logarithm, trigonometric functions, and inverse hyperbolic functions), but usually no limit."

Comment: Btw. @vrugtehagel. You can't get any closer to vagueness in mathematics than the "definition" of "closed-form". Saying that the natural numbers are either $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ or $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is one thing. Saying that they contain "numbers like 4,5,99,202" and "some other well-known numbers" is quite a different thing. The latter is the analogue of the definition of "closed-form". You can unfortunately not base proofs upon such a characterization. Going from undergraduate to graduate is a big step, in a mathematician's life.